# Cassandra failover policy

Tags: cassandra

In the official manual, they don't recommend failback to remote DC if local DC is down. It might cause many unforeseen problems.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/load_balancing/#local-only

Let's say I have 2 clusters: one is the main cluster and the other is the backup cluster, A and B respectively and they are in the same data center.

I want to implement a feature: if A cluster is down, switch to B cluster.

Is it OK to use [DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html)?

If I use [DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html), does it cause any issue?

Comment: what is the point of having 2 clusters?  I recommend to look to following paper on the fault-tolerant design: https://www.datastax.com/resources/whitepaper/designing-fault-tolerant-applications-datastax-and-apache-cassandratm

Comment: It is my company convention. One is the main cluster and the other is backup. If the main cluster is down, switch to the backup cluster.

Comment: Cassandra doesn't work that way. Against what do you want to protect?

Comment: From my company perspective, they want Cassandra never down. So our solution is that one Cassandra is main and the other standby. It is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)

Comment: This is not how Cassandra works - it's "always on" solution, even during upgrades. You achieve the fault tolerance by splitting the cluster into data centers, geo-distributed between multiple locations/physical DCs.  For example: https://www.datastax.com/blog/2018/03/six-plus-years-and-counting-no-downtime-seriously